# Error counting vowels and consonant progr

Tags: java

I'm trying make a program that takes string input and count the number of Vowels and Consonants but I end up counting the Consonants alone as initial Input length.

```
String x;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int VowelCount=0;
        int ConsonantCount=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence: ");
        x=sc.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
            if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("a")||x.equalsIgnoreCase("e")||x.equalsIgnoreCase("i")||x.equalsIgnoreCase("o")||x.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
                VowelCount+= 1;
            }
            else{
                ConsonantCount+=1;

            }


        }
        System.out.println("Consonant " + ConsonantCount+"\nVowels " + VowelCount);
```

Comment: Think through your logic:  `x` is the entire String, and you're testing if the entire String equals "a" or "e",... which will never be true unless x holds only a single char.

Comment: Instead, you want `if (x.charAt(i) == 'a' || x.charAt(i) == 'e' || ....`. .. and there are even cleaner ways of doing this

Comment: Thanks a lot, been trying to fix this for a while now ‍♂️

Comment: You could do, `Set<Character> vowelSet = Set.of('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U');` and then, `for (char c : text.replaceAll("\\W", "").toUpperCase().toCharArray()) { if (vowelSet.contains(c)) { ...`